# MAUI - CollectionView jump / focus to next entry

Tags: xaml, xamarin, maui, .net-maui

I have a Collectionview , where each item is a entry to fill in one char.

I would like to automaticly jump from entry one to entry two , and so on.

How can I access the 'next' entry from the CollectionView ? So that I can set the focus on the next entry ?

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp2.RowControlPage"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MauiApp2.ViewModel"
             Title="RowControlPage">
    <CollectionView>
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <CollectionView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type vm:CharViewModel}">
                <vm:CharViewModel CharExpected="A" CharTyped="A" CharIndex="1" WordExpected="ABCDEF"/>
                <vm:CharViewModel CharExpected="B" CharTyped="B" CharIndex="2" WordExpected="ABCDEF"/>
                <vm:CharViewModel CharExpected="C" CharTyped="C" CharIndex="3" WordExpected="ABCDEF"/>
                <vm:CharViewModel CharExpected="D" CharTyped="D" CharIndex="4" WordExpected="ABCDEF"/>
                <vm:CharViewModel CharExpected="E" CharTyped="E" CharIndex="5" WordExpected="ABCDEF"/>
                <vm:CharViewModel CharExpected="F" CharTyped="F" CharIndex="6" WordExpected="ABCDEF"/>
            </x:Array>
        </CollectionView.ItemsSource>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Entry 
                    Text="{Binding CharExpected}"
                    Name="{Binding CharIndex}"
                    ReturnCommand="{Binding NewCommand}"
                    WidthRequest="70"
                    HeightRequest="70"
                    FontSize="34"
                    Margin="5"
                    Keyboard="Text"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                    TextTransform="Uppercase"
                    ReturnType="Send" 
                    MaxLength="1">
                </Entry>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Entry, just set ReturnType="Next". MAUI will do it for you:

````
<Entry 
   Text="{Binding CharExpected}"
   Name="{Binding CharIndex}"
   ReturnCommand="{Binding NewCommand}"
   WidthRequest="70"
   HeightRequest="70"
   FontSize="34"
   Margin="5"
   Keyboard="Text"
   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
   TextTransform="Uppercase"
   ReturnType="Next" 
   MaxLength="1">
</Entry>```
````

Comment: Nothing changed after adding ``` ReturnType="Next" ```