# Make focus go to next entry in a collection view

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit

I have an application in .Net Maui that uses a collection view with an entry field and after the collection view one static entry field. If you are currently focused on the first entry in the collection view and hit tab or enter it will not navigate to the next entry in the collection view and focus on the static entry field. I need to find the best way to have the entry focus on the next entry in the collection view on complete.

I have tried changing the return type of the collection view entry field to Next and also tried the community toolkit SetFocusOnEntryCompletedBehavior function and both result in the same behavior of not navigating to the next entry from the collection view. Very similar to this issue that doesnt seem to be resolved. [MAUI - CollectionView jump / focus to next entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73152302/maui-collectionview-jump-focus-to-next-entry)

Comment: Sounds like Maui doesn't find the next entry, when they are added via collectionview. If you like, you can make a public github repo with enough code to run and see the failure. Then create a new `github maui issue`, with link to repo. This helps devs test it and fix it.

Comment: You cannot do that as the entry is placed in the DataTemplate of Collectionview. Also cannot access the entry control if use the x:Name.

Comment: "Tried the community toolkit SetFocusOnEntryCompletedBehavior function." I am very interested to see how you did that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround for you. You could try the following code:

**Step1** Create a custom control  , let's call it *MyEntry* (MyEntry.cs) which subclass **Entry**:

In this control we attach a BindableProperty **IsExpectedToFocusProperty** which we used it to judge whether it is goning to be focused. We also registered a new method **OnIsExpectedToFocus** to detect propertyChanged for our control. For info about BindableProperty, you could refer to [Bindable properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/bindable-properties?view=net-maui-7.0).

*MyEntry.cs*,

```
public class MyEntry : Entry
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty IsExpectedToFocusProperty = BindableProperty.Create("IsExpectedToFocus", typeof(bool), typeof(MyEntry), false, propertyChanged:OnIsExpectedToFocus);

    public bool IsExpectedToFocus
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(IsExpectedToFocusProperty);
        set => SetValue(IsExpectedToFocusProperty, value);
    }

    static void OnIsExpectedToFocus(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        // Property changed implementation goes here
        if ((bool)newValue == true)
        {
            (bindable as Entry).Focus();
        }         
    }
}
```

**Step2** Consume custom control in CollectionView. We define the ReturnCommand and its parameter. we will bind them in the MainPageViewModel.

*MainPage.xaml,*

```
<CollectionView x:Name="mycoll" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCollection}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
                <local:MyEntry x:Name="myentry" Focused="myentry_Focused"
                        IsExpectedToFocus="{Binding IsExpectedToFocus}"
                        Text="{Binding Title,Mode=TwoWay}" TextColor="Black"
                        ReturnCommand="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainPageViewModel}}, Path=ReturnCommand}"
                        ReturnCommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

In .cs file:

```
void myentry_Focused(System.Object sender, Microsoft.Maui.Controls.FocusEventArgs e)
{
    var entry = sender as Entry;
    foreach (var item in viewModel.ItemCollection)
    {
        if (entry.BindingContext != item)
        {
            item.IsExpectedToFocus = false;         
        }
    }
}
```

**Step3** Design our MainPageViewModel. I define an ObservableCollection which ItemSource will bind to. And add three items just for test.

Then I think the most important part is to design the **Command**. Let me explain it briefly. When we press the entry of an Entry, we fire the **ReturnCommand** and get current Item through **ReturnCommandParameter**. We get the index of current Item in ItemCollection. So the next entry which needs to be focused corresponds to the index+1 Item. Then we changed the **IsExpectedToFocus** of the next entry and fire the **OnIsExpectedToFocus** method which set the entry be focused. Done!

*MainPageViewModel.cs*

```
public class MainPageViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> ItemCollection { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

    public Command ReturnCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command<Item>((e) =>
            {
                e.IsExpectedToFocus = false;
                int index = ItemCollection.IndexOf(e); // get the current index
                if (index != -1)
                {
                    int nextIndex;
                    // if last entry, next index is 0, else index +1
                    if (index < (ItemCollection.Count() - 1))
                    {
                        nextIndex = index + 1;
                        ItemCollection[nextIndex].IsExpectedToFocus = true;

                    }
                    else if(index == (ItemCollection.Count() - 1))
                    {
                        nextIndex = 0;
                        ItemCollection[nextIndex].IsExpectedToFocus = true;
                    }  
                }
            });
        }        
    }

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        //add three item for test
        ItemCollection.Add(
        new Item
        {
            Title = "12345",
            IsExpectedToFocus = false
        }) ;
        ItemCollection.Add(
        new Item
        {
            Title = "23456",
            IsExpectedToFocus = false
        });

        ItemCollection.Add(
        new Item
        {
            Title = "34567",
            IsExpectedToFocus = false
        });
    }
}
```

Also, this is Item.cs, should implement **INotifyPropertyChanged**

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string title;
    public bool isExpectedToFocus;

    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return title;
        }

        set
        {
            title = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Title)));
        }
    }

    public bool IsExpectedToFocus
    {
        get
        {
            return isExpectedToFocus;
        }
        set
        {
            isExpectedToFocus = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsExpectedToFocus)));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

[image]

Hope it works for you.